# Kubernetes - Python application memory management

Tags: python, memory, kubernetes

I'm having this "issue" I can't find a solution.

I just started working with Kubernetes and here in the company we have an environment where we are running some Java and Python applications.

For Java applications, we can set some values for JVM to define memory usage, but for Python... As far as I know, there isn't this possibility.

Is there a way for me to limit Python application memory usage like Java? Or the only way is to configure my resources attributes in YAML file?

Thanks in advance for your help and time.

Comment: you can control the container resource usage in kubernetes manifests and python cant use more than that

Comment: Yes, and while doing what @IjazAhmadKhan says, just monitor usage for a while to adjust the settings. Also know that kubernetes finds program crashes "normal" behavior an just restarts your app. So out of memory has for most applications limited impact (just run multiple pods with your program and have failure resilient code)